# JavaScript Function not getting any values from WordPress form SELECT element

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm having a difficulty with WordPress form.

I am writing a code which will be working based on entries from WordPress form. But the issue is when I try passing values from the form to JS function using HTML, it works perfectly. But when I try to upload the script files and link the script file with form, then the issue begins.

### HTML code

```
<select name='city' class='city' id="field_cityname-0">
    <option value>Location</option>
    <option value='Option 1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='Option 2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='Option 3'>Option 3</option>
    <option value='Option 4'>Option 4</option>
    <option value='Option 5'>Option 5</option>
    <option value='Option 6'>Option 6</option>
    <option value='Option 7'>Option 7</option>
</select>
```

### JS Function

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    //map settings
    });

    let markers = [];

    const cities = {
    //Map markers
    };

    const addmarker = (lat, lng, name ) => {
        return new google.maps.Marker({    
        });
    };

    //Test function for check values passing or not
    var newElement = document.getElementById("field_cityname-0");
    newElement.addEventListener('change', function(){
        console.log(this.value + " city selected");
    });


    document.querySelector('#field_cityname-0').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( this.value != '' && cities.hasOwnProperty( this.value ) ) {
            markers.forEach( mkr => mkr.setMap( null ) );
            let obj = cities[ this.value ];
      
            markers.push( addmarker( obj.lat, obj.lng, obj.name ) );
            console.log("The city is "+this.value);
      
            return true;
        }
        alert('Oh no ' + this.value + ' not found')
        })
  
    }

window.initMap = initMap;
```

With HTML select element, I changed the **//Test function** position from inside to outside the initMap function or from outside to inside, it worked perfectly. Passed values properly.

But with WordPress form if I change the position of //Test function from inside to outside the initMap function, the JS code received the data from form SELECT element. But if I put the //Test function again inside of the initMap function, it's not working. No values receiving from Form and I can't figure out why.

Is there a any way to pass the values when using with WordPress form?
**field_cityname-0** is the id of WordPress form select element.